# Selenium python how to click a button if button name is save

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium-webdriver

I have below html.

```
<button>save</button>
<button>Cancel</button>
<button>View</button>
```

I want to click on button if name is save.

```
button = driver.find_element_by_xpath(
            "(//button[contains(@name, 'save')])")
```

I am able to do it if button has a name. But if button has no name like my example how can I click on it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take button txt by XPATH.

```
button = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//button[text()="save"]')

button.click()
```

For more details [click](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/locating-elements.html)

Answer (score 0):

Like this if has no name:

```
button = driver.find_element_by_xpath(
            "(//button[contains(@name, '')])")
```

Comment: There has 3 buttons I want to click on save button. and every buttons has no name attribute.